# Unix Shell Scripting - How to read values from a file line by line with position delimeter

Tags: shell, unix

I am a java developer and dont have experience in shell scripting
I have this code in Shell script which basically reads a file

```
if [ -f $DATA_FILE ] ; then

    # Next - convert the data into insert statements
    nawk -F\^ '
    {
        #I believe $115 is the 115th record in the data file in each lines
        if ( $115 == "NULL" )
        {
            $115 = "";
        }

        output = "INSERT INTO DLRINFO";
        output = output " (C_DCS_DLR_NBR,";
        output = output " C_DLR_NBR,";
        output = output " C_LOC_COMP,";
        output = output " T_STAMP_CREATD,";
        output = output " I_CREATOR)";
        output = output " VALUES";
        output = output " (ZZZ" $1 "ZZZ,";
        output = output " ZZZ" $115 "ZZZ,";
        output = output " ZZZ02ZZZ,";
        output = output " current timestamp,";
        output = output " ZZZC3RZZZ);";

        print output
    }' /tmp/$MY_NAME.1.out > /tmp/$MY_NAME.2.out
```

which is actually reading a file line by line with values that are delimeted by '^'

now the file format is getting changed and I need to delimeter it using position.

Old file format:

```
"70075"^"RIVERSIDE SUBARU"^"100 CHENALL RD"^"LIT RCK"^"AR"^"72223-5981"^"A"^"5019990000"^"5014999008"^"N/A"^""^"334"^"MBF - SOUTHERN"^"T1010DC"^"D CLAIRE"^"Y"^"OWNERS INSURANCE CO"^20150501^""^""^"THE WINROCK GROUP, INC."^""^"Y"^+100.^""^""^""^""^""^^""^""^""^""^""^^""^""^""^""^""^^""^""^""^""^""^^""^""^""^""^""^^""^""^""^""^""^^""^""^""^""^""^^""^""^""^""^""^^""^""^""^""^""^^""^""^""^""^""^^""^""^""^""^""^^""^""^""^""^""^^""^""^""^""^""^^""^""^""^""^""^^"Unknown"^"00"^"Z -M"^"A"^"MARKET #999 SPECIAL ENTITIES"^"D CLAIRE-T1900DC"^"98102"^"02"
```

(This is the first line from the data file.)

Now the new file format would be like

```
136324 70051 2015-02-01 36224 70900 1DR 136326 70023 2015-02-01 36326 70050 YY1WS 136328 70024 2015-02-01 36328 70061 YY1WS
```

(This is the first line from the data file.)
*each record is of a fixed size first record is of 5 characters and second of 1 character it doesn't have any delimeters between them.

Required Output:
I have to capture record that is of first five characters and record from the position 30 of five character value.

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "delimiter it using position"?  Do you mean that each record is a fixed size without any delimiters between them?

Comment: _"now the file format is getting changed"_  You might want to show an example of the new file format.

Comment: This will be the single line of the file. @jwodder yes each record is of a fixed size first record is of 5 characters and second of 1 character it doesn't have any delimeters between them

Comment: @JAVAUSER Put the sample line in the question where you can use the full power of stackoverflow's formatting options, rather than spread ambiguously over multiple comments.  Don't leave us guessing what "this" means.  Spell everything out explicitly.  Just as one example  your code uses `$115` but _nothing_ in your comments indicates where we would find that in your new format.  For you given input line, show what output you want.

Comment: Agree with all comments above. All you may need to know is that `awk`, just like `java` has a substring function. the prototype is `substr("string", stPos, len)`. If you now have a fixed-length record, you change your `$115` references to something like `.... substr($0,300,3)`. (from the whole line ($0), go to postion 300, and take 3 characters worth). Good luck.

Comment: @John1024 Thank you, being new, to post a qusetion in stack overflow I wasn't aware of the edits. will explain everything in detail from here on .

Comment: @shellter Thank you I think substr("string", stPos, len) is what I am looking for.

Comment: JAVAUSER, Very good.  I applied formatting to your sample date (the `{}` button in the editor): this shows you input literally without added line breaks.  Verify that this looks right.  The goal of StackOverflow is to develop a library of Q and A to help future programmers.  Consequently, if @shelter's suggestion is right and he writes an answer, you may want to accept it (click the green tick mark next to it).  This marks the answer as helpful and the question as solved.

Comment: @John1024 looks like shelter commented on the thread I dont see a tick mark. I will add an answer to my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @shelter

> **All you may need to know is that awk, just like java has a substring function. the prototype is substr("string", stPos, len). If you now
>   have a fixed-length record, you change your $115 references to
>   something like .... substr($0,300,3). (from the whole line ($0), go to
>   postion 300, and take 3 characters worth).**

this is what I was looking for. substr("string", stPos, len) is all I need